# Wrap std::function in class with function name as string

Tags: c++, string, function

I'm trying to wrap `std::function` in a class with adds a readable `string` of the function name to `std::function`.

I did come up with this simple class
**(defined in header.hpp)**

```
template <typename... Args>
class CExtended_Function
{
public:
    explicit CExtended_Function(
        const std::function<void(Args...)>& func_type, const std::string& func_name)
        : func(func_type)
        , function_name(func_name)
    {
    }

    /// Function
    const std::function<void(Args...)> func;

    /// Function Name
    const std::string function_name;
};
```

My own make function looks like this. The Idea is to pass the Function Name to the make function as a template argument. And the make function should create a `std::function` instance and a `std::string` instance.

**(defined in header.hpp)**

```
template <typename Func_T, typename... Args>
CExtended_Function<Args...> Make_Extended_Function()
{
    std::function<void(Args...)> func(Func_T);
    std::string func_name(NCommonFunctions::type_name<Func_T>());
    CExtended_Function<Args...> res(func, func_name);

    return res;
}
```

where `type_name<My_Function>()` returns the name of the function as `std::string_view`

**defined in header.hpp**

```
template <class T>
constexpr std::string_view type_name();
```

However when using my make function like this

**used in source.cpp**

```
static void Test_Callback();

auto test = Make_Extended_Function<Test_Callback>();
```

I'm getting the error :

> Symbol 'Make_Extended_Function' could not be resolved

Could you give me a hint why I'm getting this error?

Comment: Are you one of the many that tried to [implement a template in a .cpp file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/495021/why-can-templates-only-be-implemented-in-the-header-file)?

Comment: nope all templates are defined and implemented in a header file.

Comment: Does the problem go away if you put everything in a single file?

Comment: I wrote this as an answer, but then I realized that this might not be the problem and deleted it. Regardless, you are passing the function as a type parameter, but it is not a type, please take a look at https://godbolt.org/z/NnESxJ . It this what you wanted to achieve? If you apply my fix, does it compile?

Comment: @L.F. nope it was not an include problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a couple of things you may need to change in your code:

1. Test_Callback is a function, you can only pass function pointer as a non-type template argument. I.e. it should be `auto test = Make_Extended_Function<&Test_Callback>();` instead;
2. If you're passing a function pointer as template argument, the syntax is `template<function+pointer_type function pointer>`(similar to template), so make_extended_function should be `template <auto Func_T, typename... Args>
   CExtended_Function<Args...> Make_Extended_Function()` instead (I use "auto" here to make things easier). And the same for type_name()

Sample code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>
#include <string_view>

using namespace std;
namespace NCommonFunctions {
template <auto T>
std::string type_name() { return "a_name"; }
}
template <typename... Args>
class CExtended_Function
{
public:
    explicit CExtended_Function(
        const std::function<void(Args...)>& func_type, const std::string& func_name)
        : func(func_type)
        , function_name(func_name)
    {
    }

    /// Function
    const std::function<void(Args...)> func;

    /// Function Name
    const std::string function_name;
};

template <auto Func_T, typename... Args>
CExtended_Function<Args...> Make_Extended_Function()
{
    std::function<void(Args...)> func(Func_T);
    std::string func_name(NCommonFunctions::type_name<Func_T>());
    CExtended_Function<Args...> res(func, func_name);

    return res;
}
 void Test_Callback() { cout << "test" << endl; }
int main () {
    auto test = Make_Extended_Function<&Test_Callback>();
    test.func();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`Make_Extended_Function` expects types. you provide function pointer, so an error.

The easier fix would probably be to change `Make_Extended_Function` to:

```cpp
template <typename... Args>
CExtended_Function<Args...>
Make_Extended_Function(const std::function<void(Args...)>& f, const std::string& name)
{
    return CExtended_Function<Args...>(f, name);
}
```

(but you have to call it with a `std::function` to allow deduction).

`NCommonFunctions::type_name` seems to have identical issues than `Make_Extended_Function`.

A probably better fix would be to drop std::function and take functor directly:

```cpp
template <typename F>
class CExtended_Function
{
public:
    explicit CExtended_Function(
        const F& f, const std::string& name)
        : f(f)
        , name(name)
    {
    }

    F f;
    std::string name;
};
```